# YAML C# Add new line between items

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, formatting, yamldotnet

I'm looking for a way of adding new line per every new line (as I show below: "before" and "after")

```cs
var yamlSerializer = new SerializerBuilder()
.AddNewLinePerEveryNewItem() // smth like this or similar API
.Build()
```

Before:

```yaml
first1:
  hello: true
  world: true
there:
  a: true
  b: true
  c: true
first2:
  a: false
```

After:

```yaml
first1:
  hello: true
  world: true

there:
  a: true
  b: true
  c: true

first2:
  a: false
```

Comment: This may be possible, but I can't imagine it would be simple. Serializers like this use recursion, which abstracts each layer in a way that doesn't make it clear what layer you're on (because it simplifies things, and that's not normally important). If you were to implement something like this, it would likely apply to *all* of the items, not just the top-most layer of items.

Comment: It seems that [someone has been working in such feature](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/pull/804) for the library [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet), but it has not been merged yet into the master branch. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/pull/873) there to move things forward, if it helps.